# High-rise building

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> Jimmy stood waiting alone at a bus stop on the outskirts of the city, gazing toward the high-rise buildings of the city center towering up a few miles away.

- Is a high-rise building just any tall building? (I've been told that it's used of apartment buildings)
- Would it be more natural to just write "tall buildings" instead?
- Would you prefer "gazing toward the high-rise buildings towering up a few miles away downtown" instead?

Comment: What do you mean by 'natural'?

Comment: _High-rise_ is usually used of modern buildings with many identical storeys.

Comment: The Shard has many storeys, but none, I think, are identical, as it tapers from bottom to top. It is mentioned in the International Journal of High-Rise Buildings, Vol 7 No 2.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I did say _usually_! I meant, as distinct from church towers, town halls and the like.

Comment: Would "high-rise buildings" include any tall building in a city - apartment buildings as well as office buildings?

Comment: Yes, it includes both of those.

Comment: If you want to sound even more idiomatic, leave out the word **buildings**: "...gazing towards the high-rises of the city center...."

Answer (score 1):

High-rise can be used of office-blocks, retail stores, and not only apartments.  It wouldn't be used about (for example) a cathedral, or telecommunications tower. So "high-rise" is fine in this context. There may be some technical or legal implications to "high-rise" but I'm guessing that this isn't important to this context.

Downtown means the same as "city center",  Downtown is mostly used in American English.

Answer (score 0):

There are various definitions of 'high rise' in relation to buildings; of course it is trivially true that a 'high rise' building is taller than some height, but where to fix that height? Bodies such as local government construction licensing departments, fire and rescue services, and building safety authorities may use different standards. For example, in the UK, a high-rise building may be one where some occupants need to use a lift ('elevator') to reach their destination, where the height is above the reach of available fire-fighting equipment, or where the height can have a serious effect on evacuation. Typically this is regarded as more than 7-10 storeys, or 23-30 metres, although some residential housing classifications use 18 metres. Following a fire in 2019, in a building 19 metres tall, the UK government started consultations about reducing the starting height for a 'high-rise' classification to 11 metres.

[Designing High-rise buildings](https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/High-rise_building)